# Get typed information from subscribe callback for Observable.fromEvent()

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables, angular-observable

I have this:

```js
this.keydownSub = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup').subscribe(v => {

  if(v){
    if(v.keyCode == '37'){
      this.goLeft();
    }
    if(v.keyCode == '39'){
      this.goRight();
    }
  }
});
```

the problem is that there is no type information for the variable `v`, and that's because the event type is dynamic ('keyup' is used).

Is there some way to use something like this:

```js
this.keydownSub = Observable.fromEvent(document).keyUp().subscribe(v => {

  if(v){
    if(v.keyCode == '37'){
      this.goLeft();
    }
    if(v.keyCode == '39'){
      this.goRight();
    }
  }
});
```

so that static typing information is possible/available?

Comment: If I use this `(v: KeyboardEvent)`, that should be correct, but I kinda had to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fromEvent` observable creator is a generic function. If you know the type that corresponds to the event, you can specify that type as a type parameter. Like this:

```ts
const event$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, "keyup");
```

Comment: whoa that's weird syntax, haven't see that before

Comment: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/types/generics.md#design-pattern-convenience-generic